# How to insert an image from client-side into an editor?

Tags: javascript, css, editor

Like an "insert" menu, by which to insert an image into the editor, using JavaScript, I've no idea what's the solution at all,

should be in 2 steps:

1. Let the user choose an image (this should be doable by an `input type=file`).
2. Insert the chosen image into editing context(don't know how to implement).

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to achieve this without uploading the image to your server, since the only reference you can have inside the text area is to a public website (i.e. not the users hard drive).

I'd recommend checking [IMCE](http://ufku.com/drupal/imce/demo); that's what I use.

It allows the user to upload images. Together with a nice WYGIWYS editor such as [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) it works like a charm.

Comment: But it's without any place to upload the image to,
Is there any other editor that integrates uploading utility?